# Custom Hook with Multiple API Endpoints

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, service

I have a React v>17 application that in almost every component fetches information from an API using some service helpers.

Here is an example of the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSubaccounts = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const res = await getSubaccounts();
        setSubaccounts(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
        // console.log(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    fetchSubaccounts();
  }, []);
```

And here is an example of the implementation of the +100 service helpers using a simple axios instance.

```
export const deleteSubaccount = () => instance.post(`/client/subaccounts/`);
```

Nothing new, but after repeating this a lot of times I decided to refactor and extract some of this code to a custom hook. However I can't find the right way of doing this.
I think that creating a custom hook such as the [typical](https://dev.to/shaedrizwan/building-custom-hooks-in-react-to-fetch-data-4ig6) `useFetch()` that receives the URL isn't the best implementation for this situation (because any changes in the endpoints would have to be done in every use of the hook and not having them all in one place). Are there any alternatives to reuse the services or should I think of different implementation?

Comment: But if you want to reuse this hook you must have passed some param to it.

Comment: Yes I know, but I am wondering which would be the cleanest implementation that allows me to have all the endpoints at the same place so I can modify them massively to simplify maintenance.